# Crud operations on client only collection in meteor

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have a client only collection

```
feedComments=new Mongo.Collection('feeds');
```

Using meteor composite I'm publishing few records to this collection,

when I try to update the collection in client

```
feedComments.update({_id:result._id},{$set:{name:"xxx"}});
```

It is not allowing me to it is throwing error

```
method not found
```

why can't I insert or update the client only collection,why do client collections don't have those methods?

don't know this can be done,but I tried with this too

```
feedComments.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        return false;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: i guess you defined collection in variable `feeds` and you are acceesing with `feedComments`

Comment: @ajduke that's typo mistake

Comment: okay. In your declaration, are you trying to define client-only collection?

Comment: yes,that is my question

Comment: okay, try define client-only collection like this- `feedComments=new Mongo.Collection(null);`. Observe `null` passed

Comment: I'm following this blog http://braindump.io/meteor/2014/09/20/publishing-to-an-alternative-clientside-collection-in-meteor.html, it shows name so I followed, if it gives null, it is working thanks for the help. The answer by @Sasikanth worked too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to perform crud operations on client only collections user `_collection`

try

```
feedComments._collection.update({_id:result._id},{$set:{name:"xxx"}});
```